# Problem running .jar file while deploying my ktor application to docker

Tags: docker, jar

Am deploying my ktor application to docker but am experiencing problems.The application runs fine when i run the server locally but when i deploy it to docker the .jar file brings up the following errors

Comment: Could you please post the content of the `Application.kt` file?

Comment: thank you @AlekseiTirman. I will greatly appreciate for any help

Comment: Most likely your problem is related to HikariCP. I've found an issue with the similar stack trace here https://github.com/apache/shardingsphere/issues/8570.

Comment: Thank you. Let me continue digging dipper.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine` at the top of your `Dockerfile`

Comment: Sorry i ommited it while posting.I already have it in my code.